# Why my new website domain sometimes directed me to the old webpage

Tags: php, html, web, server, hosting

I have a website that was hosted in n*agahoster, which already expired (with active status) since our company didn't want to use the domain example.com and instead change the hosting place to a government's server which resulting to a new domain example.gov.xx

The procedure was not hard, since there is someone who handle the server, and I just gave the backup files (the public_html as well as the database) from old hosting place. Everything went smoothly, until I tried to access the new domain (example.gov.xx), instead of showing me the actual webpage, it directed me to old domain (example.com) which already expired and can't be access. This only happened on a certain time though, if I keep refreshing the web, using different browser, or try to access it later, it will show the correct domain as well as the webpage, **BUT** it only appeared in my own PC, and if my friends want to access the new domain (example.gov.xx) it will still direct them to the old webpage (example.com) and they have to keep on trying or use different browser, to actually access the correct new domain.

Why can this happen? I already change the link of the old domain to the new domain in my index.php file. Is there anything that I should add or change? Is it the .htaccess file?

v3/index.php

```
<script>
     setTimeout(function(){
       window.location.href = 'http://example.gov.xx/v3/public/'; //The old one is example.com/v3/public
       // window.location.href = 'http://localhost/folder/v3/public/?SI-xxxxxxxxx=YWN0PWhvbWU%3D'; //ignore this
     }, 10000);
</script>
```

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: @KenLee so to be able to access the correct domain and sometimes won't, is normal?Because of the DNS update/adjustment?

Comment: (1) you have set 10 seconds for redirection ? shorten it to say 1.5 seconds (2) Instead of using javascript, consider using PHP location header redirection (3) Please be reminded that example.gov.xx and example.com are actually two different, distinct domains

Comment: (1) Okay will change it to 1.5 (2) Is there any difference, since it's work fine atm..., but if it will solve the direction problem, I will change it asap (3) I know it well, that is why it is weird for the new domain to sometimes direct me to the old unused domain @KenLee

Comment: regarding the DNS TTL you mentioned before, I already contacted someone who handle the server and he said it was set to 300 sec (5 min) @KenLee

Comment: Further recommended action: Please clear the browser cache and re-try

Comment: Is there any connection to my previous hosting place? Since the status is still active with overdue payment (can't access to the web but can retrieve the file for backup). Should I remove it? Since it really frustrating, it always direct to old unused domain

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include your DNS record for your new and old domains?  It would be good to see both the `NS` records which are set at your domain registrar and the `A` and `CNAME` records from your DNS host.

Answer (score 0):

find and replace in file also DB old domain name to new domain name manualy.
also from social media links use htaccess to redirect old url to new url.

Comment: The files which contain old domain url were already edited/changed/removed to the new domain url. The DB works pretty well. And as for the htaccess, may I know which line should I change/edit or maybe add a new line?

Answer (score 0):

If this is only happening for your computer there are two possibilities:

1. Your browser has the redirect cached.  Browsers aggressively cache redirects.  So if you tried to access the new site when it actually was redirecting, your browser will remember that. You need to clear your browser cache before testing again.
2. The DNS isn't correct on your local machine. This is often caused by having entries in `/etc/hosts` (or `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows) that you created for development that point the new domain to the IP address of the old host.

Comment: It is not only in my PC, everyone who tried to access the new domain URL will be directed to the old domain URL, both domain have different name one is example.com and the new one is example.gov.xx

Comment: You say "BUT it only appeared in my own PC" which I thought meant the redirect.  But maybe you mean something else?